# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 141

Tags: magento-2.2.1

Magento 2.2.1. Recently I have deleted one unused store and my magento has been broken with error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 141

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 141
#0 /var/www//vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryRepository.php(141): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', '141')
#1 /var/www//app/code/TemplateMonster/CatalogImagesGrid/Block/CatalogImage/Grid.php(78): Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository->get('141')
#2 /var/www//app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/TemplateMonster_CatalogImagesGrid/templates/catalog/widget_image_grid.phtml(3): TemplateMonster\CatalogImagesGrid\Block\CatalogImage\Grid->getCategory()
#3 /var/www/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/www.le...')
#4 /var/www/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(TemplateMonster\CatalogImagesGrid\Block\CatalogImage\Grid), '/var/www/www.le...', Array)
```

I have restored site and db from working backup - same error! of course, cache cleaned, var, generation etc deleted, content redeployed. constantly getting same error.

admin part works OK.

Please advice what is the nature of this error?

Which ID cannot be found? category? site? this driving me nuts already..

Comment: It's looking for category ID 141.

Comment: thanks, actually it's more or less clear, but why? i never had category with such ID, i never touched categories.
why restored backup have same error? it looks like something deeply cached, but what..

Comment: i checked table catalog_category_entity from recent backups - there is no such id's, there is id's 1..135 and 267..343, so it's not clear why site started to call such id...

Comment: I see your are using custom theme - I think you should ask theme seller then.

Comment: already did, but they didn't provide support during weekend.

Comment: go to all categories and save them by the store view you have now, to be updated with your store

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `TemplateMonster_CatalogImagesGrid` is searching for non-existent category. As far as i can see, there are widget references.

You should check if you have any instances of `CatalogImagesGrid` widget in `Content/widgets`. Widget parameters might contain category configurations.

Answer (score 1):

**Check**

Admin -> Stores > All Stores -> Main Website Store -> Root Category --> Default Category

Its Work for me..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the way I fixed it was to go to the **Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog** and setting up the value of `Use Flat Catalog Category` and `Use Flat Catalog Product` to **Yes**

Note: Use these commands after making the changes

- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and following what Matias Anoniz worked for me.
I had an error pop up on the `Admin -> Stores -> All Stores` page that said my new store didn't have a category associated with it. To fix this I did the following:

> Admin -> Stores -> All Stores -> [Pick the new store in the Store
>   Column] -> Root Category -> [Set it to Default Category]

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```